# Django sockets don't work in production, when deployed in Azure Web App

Tags: python, django, azure, sockets, daphne

Python version 3.10

Recently my websockets stopped working when deployed in Azure. I am using Python Django with Daphne. When run locally everything works fine also if ssh into the web server and run another instance of Django, I can locally also connect to the websocket. But when I'm trying to connect to websockets in production as a client, the socket connection instantly fails. Also when viewing logs it seems like they get redirected to HTTP requests? That is why I get a 404 error

```
Not Found: /ws/notifications/
169.254.129.1 - - [01/Jul/2023:10:14:35 +0000] "GET /ws/notifications/?token={myToken}HTTP/1.1" 404 2753 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/114.0.0.0 Safari/537.36"
```

The code gets built and deployed without any errors, so I am confused to why this is happening. My front-end is also calling the correct uri `wss://api.pickme.lv/ws/notifications/`. Also as I mentioned they were working previously, now they just stopped. Please ask if you require additional information, because tbh I have no clue where to start with this.

I also have websockets enabled in my Azure config

```
 ],
  "vnetPrivatePortsCount": 0,
  "vnetRouteAllEnabled": true,
  "webSocketsEnabled": true,
  "websiteTimeZone": null,
  "windowsFxVersion": null,
  "xManagedServiceIdentityId": null
}
```

Comment: Ok I found out. Just in case some one needs this. Azure Oryx for Django Web does not run daphne, like `py manage.py runserver` does. So you need to run it after deploying for example `daphne {your_app_name}.asgi:application --port 8002 --bind 0.0.0.0`. Also I had to change the port for wsgi. `gunicorn {your_app_name}.wsgi:application --bind 0.0.0.0:8001`. After that I setup a nginx reverse proxy, to listen on port 8000 and then route the requests to the correct service. Works like a charm.
Still no clue why sockets worked for a few days before this.